# Long page number not properly right aligned in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, titletoc

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
    [2em]
    {\normalfont}
    {\contentslabel{1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{}

\clearpage
\section{}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{88}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Here the last page number results in an `Overfull \hbox`. How should I properly configure the `\titlecontents` so that the page numbers can be right aligned regardless of its length?

Comment: Besides `\@pnumwidth` (the max size for page numbers), there is also `\@tocrmarg` (the right margin for TOC).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the page number width by redefining `\@pnumwidth`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{4em}
\makeatother
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
    [2em]
    {\normalfont}
    {\contentslabel{1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{4em}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{}

\clearpage
\section{}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{88}
\section{}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link proposed by @DavidPurton in the comment to the question, enlarging `\contentsmargin` (or perhaps internally `\@pnumwidth`) is a solution. However, to make the other entries look better, the change should better be made local (which should be done in the final run when the page numbers of the contents are stable).

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\bgroup\contentsmargin{...}}
...
\addtocontents{toc}{\egroup}
```

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
    [2em]
    {\normalfont}
    {\contentslabel{1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{}

\clearpage
\section{}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{88}

\addtocontents{toc}{\bgroup\contentsmargin{1.5cm}}
\section{}
\addtocontents{toc}{\egroup}

\end{document}
```